# Escape character via serial

Tags: escaping, serial-port, character, arduino

I'm controlling a serial printer from Arduino. Now it works perfectly, but I need to send it escape characters to control some specific features of the printer. Is there a way to do that?

I need to send "ESC i".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Serial.print(27, BYTE); // ASCII code for the Escape character
Serial.print("i");
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape is ASCII character code 27. If you are programming in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), you could do:

```
putchar(27);
putchar('i');
```

Or, if you want to put the whole thing in a string, you could do something like:

```
printf("\033i");
```

The `\033` will get replaced with 33 octal, which is 27 decimal by the compiler.

Comment: The arduino's way:

Serial.print("\x1B" "i"); 

or

Serial.print("\033" "i");

Comment: 0x1B is hex and \033 is octal for decimal 27 (escape)